# Regex match characters between pipes

Tags: regex

If I have a string containing "fields" separated with pipes (`|`) like so:

> 123|123|123|FOOBAR||123|123|123

Where the characters between the pipes (`|`) will change, but the number of pipes, and the position of the field will always be the same (i.e. always directly after the 3rd occurrence of `|` until the 4th occurrence of `|`)

How can I get "FOOBAR" from the above example?

Many thanks.

Comment: In your example, you have a double pipe. Should we assume this would be for blank values of that field?

Comment: Why not just use a string.Split?

Comment: Instead of trying to solve it with regex, it is much easier to just split the string and get the forth array item.

Comment: Also, here is a part of the description of the [regex-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): *"all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool"*

Comment: `^(?:[^|]*\|){3}([^|]*)` Would match `123|123|123|FOOBAR` and has `FOOBAR` in group 1. If your regex engine supports [`\K`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) use `^(?:[^|]*\|){3}\K([^|]*)` instead, this only results in `FOOBAR`.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Apologies for not mentioning that in my OP, I will make a note to read tag descriptions before posting in future. The language I am using is C++.

Comment: @scsimon Your assumption is correct, apologies for not specifying explicitly.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer How is the question you linked when marking this as duplicate relevant to mine? As far as I can see it is asking something entirely different.

Comment: @notanalien I didn't link that question, it shows up because it was the final decision of Toto (who has a regex gold badge and can close questions). I voted for "too broad" since you still haven't included all necessary tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this and select the first group:

```
^.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|(.*?)\|
```

- ^   : Start of string
- ()  : Grouping
- .*? : Lazy quantifier
- \|  : Escape pipe character

or

```
^[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|([^|]*)\|
```

- [^|] : Not equal to pipe character

Answer (score 0):

```js
const matches = '123|123|123|FOOBAR|123|123|123'.match(/(.{3}\|){3}(.*?)\|/);

console.log(matches[2]);
```